# advice needed on Raspberry Pi project

Tags: c#, python, mysql, opencv, raspberry-pi2

Good day guys,

I need some advice on a raspberry pi project i am working on.

**Project Details**

- Using Raspberry PI and PICAM to capture image

**What does this project does?**

- The Raspberry PI + picam will be enclosed in a waterproof casing and will be lowered into the sea to capture image of ship hull to check if there is any fouling such as algae or barnacles growth on the hull.
- The captured image will then be processed using OpenCV algorithm to compare with a database of different type of fouls (algae, barnacles, shells etc) to see how many % of the image is being foul by what kind of fouling

**What have i done so far**

- Create a Python GUI that have a various buttons such as "Capture" (when pressed, it will snap a picture)
- The captured image will be uploaded into my MySQl database which i setup on my laptop to act as a server.
- I have enable remote access to MYSQL therefore my PI can connect to my MYSQL server

**Problem encountered**

- Once the PI is lowered into the sea, I have a laptop that should connect to my PI via TightVNC to run the GUI done up in PI
- Problem 1 : How do i connect my laptop to the pi locally via wireless without any connection to the internet. (accesspoint?)
- Problem 2 : Can i create a windows based application using C# that allows me to remotely control the pi? Example. i execute my windows application, there is a capture button, and when i press capture, the PiCam will snap a picture. Basically the GUI is created on windows instead of Pi so i do not have to use TightVNC to remotely access the desktop of Pi.
- Once i am not connected to any network, i could not access my PI.

Thanks. Hope to get a reply from you experts.

Comment: This may be more appropriate for http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree with @EdChum, if you had code you needed help with this place might be suitable but for a Pi specific problem you should probably go there.

Comment: If I understand your question, you need a wireless router.

Comment: I believe wifi signals won't travel very far under water. Better to have a wired connection. Up to 50m should be OK without power over ethernet.